# Can unmarried Tenants in Common report investment property income/expenses on their Schedule E's or do they need a partnership entity?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, real-estate, schedule-e, tenants-in-common

Thank you in advance to whoever decides to read this and offer their insight.

A friend and I own residential rental properties as Tenants in Common, 50/50 split under our TIC agreement. We have a federal tax question that our CPAs disagree on.

His CPA says we need to create a JV entity and get an EIN, create a partnership return for the JV, and issue K1s to ourselves.

My CPA says that's unnecessary and that we can just each report 50% of the income and expenses -- rent, P&I, insurance, etc. -- under our own Schedule E.

From my research, it seems like the difference might lie in the question of whether we are a Qualified Joint Venture. However, everything I can find about QJVs is trying to answer questions for spouses, which we are not.

Which CPA do you agree with and why?

Comment: Does your TIC Agreement have anything to say on the matter? Some of them "explicitly provide that the Taxpayer and New Co-Owner would not file a partnership tax return, or otherwise hold themselves out as members of a common business entity" - https://www.hansonbridgett.com/Publications/articles/2016-06-tax-tic-agreement-partnership

Comment: Yes, it's clear that we are not a partnership or a JV, the agreement has a section that says NO PARTNERSHIP. Another section says no co-owner shall file a partnership return without written consent of the other. It doesn't say we should or can't, just that if we did, it -- along with anything else that gives the appearance of acting as a partnership -- would require consent from the other. CPA says be that as it may, you can't have two people report the same property on individual separate returns, hence why he says you need JV.

Answer (score 1):

Your friend's CPA must be wrong, but that doesn't mean that your CPA is right: Having signed a TIC agreement, you cannot be compelled to create a JV just to enable you to file taxes. The IRS has a "come as you are" approach. The IRS does not go around forcing people to change their business arrangements. Seriously, they have enough to do without interfering in your business.

A JV may or may not be advisable, but that's another question.